# How to get SET part in SQL

Tags: java, sql, regex, oracle

I need log some SQL;

For this, I need to get some parts, such as SET

For example:

```
UPDATE table SET fieldA=132, fieldB=ABC WHERE id=10
```

Among other information I need to know which fields changed, and the value

```
fieldA => 132
fieldB => ABC
```

I tried using regex with a simple String.split(regex);
but now the sql update is more complex, with a subselect; 
My regex fails;

```
UPDATE table SET fieldA=(SELECT NVL(otherField,0) FROM table2 WHERE c=10), fieldB=ABC WHERE id=10
```

To continue running my split, I need to match only the second comma, but could not do it

I need a way to get the fields and pick the values ​​that have changed

Comment: Either do it via your java that is talking to the sql server by first selecting the row then executing your update and then selecting it again and checking what changed, or use some kind fo server internal logging where you just log what update you query you executed and then use some kind of diff to wobble through the logfile to get the actual changes

Comment: What are "regex" for split you have tried at all?

Comment: @ITroubs: on complex SQL, the value of fieldA is subselect; not the result of subselect

Comment: @RajuSharma: in first case: ","

Comment: @Falci you should post what you have attempted.

Comment: I added the `oracle` tag due to the usage of the `NVL()` function